# Postman - How to move collections between Workspaces?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-native-app

I have multiple collections on the same Workspace on Postman. Unfortunately things are starting to get messy, to many Collections from different projects on the same place.

How can I move some Collections/APIs to new Workspaces?

Comment: I think [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64493960/5675325) should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Postman v9.10.0

Click the three dots on the right of the collection name and select the action Move.

[image]

In the next screen select the workspace you want to move your collection to and click the Move Collection button.

[image]

That's it.

Answer (score 82):

1. Share a collection

[image]

2. To Workspace, select yours, and make sure you checked "Share collection and remove from this workspace"
   [image]

Voila!

Note: Worked on version 7.34.0.

Comment: That's the simple and easy way. Thanks :)

Comment: This no longer seems to work 9.1.2

Comment: From the 9.1.1 release notes: "Elements are now restricted to a single workspace at a time: Every element from now on will be restricted to being in one workspace. This is done to enable a “get what you see” experience in a workspace without worrying about how it is being managed in different workspaces.".

Comment: It is worth noting there was a significant lag when moving a collection from one workspace to another. This method does work, but there will be a short moment before the collection appears in the new workspace. Had a heart attack for a moment when I first thought the collection had vanished, but it does eventually show up.

Answer (score 25):

Just export the collection and import from another workspace.

Comment: the better way is to share collection to another workspace and remove from the current one

Comment: Ususally "better" is a word that should be used carefully. It depends on too many variables. This is another useful solution that someone could need :-)

Comment: I have found this to be a stable approach.

Answer (score 15):

**There are several Ways to do that some of them are as follows**

There is a workaround. Tested with Postman v6.1.4
Export your collection. Switch workspace. (Re-)import saved .postman_collection.json Postman will even ask you if you want to copy the collection (into the new workspace) or if you want to overwrite it (meaning move it to the new workspace)

**OR**

Delete needed collections from workspace

> A > sync > go to trash >

and restore collections to workspace B.
Hopefully, trash feature is enabled by default.

**OR**

**Sharing collections in another workspace**

[image]

In the workspaces dashboard, select a collection and then click the Share button. The collection is visible in your target workspace.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I think the simplest and fasted way to do this is to **Fork your Collection** and select the new Workspace you want to fork it into.

If you "Move" your collection by Sharing, once you delete your collection from one Workspace it will also delete it from the other.

Moving a collection by deleting and restoring or exporting and importing, forces you to leave the app.

So, just fork it is fast and easy.

Comment: Perfect answer! Took about 90 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

One way that was quick and easy was using the browser (instead of the app).

First, go to [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) using the browser and sign in. Next, create a new workspace - `Test-1`. It also gives you the option to choose the type of workspace; Personal or Team.

After creation, you now have at least 2 workspaces: the default workspace, `My Workspace`, and `Test-1`. It will create and put you inside the new workspace. Using the Collections or Environments tab, click `Add Collections/Environments to this Workspace`. You are now asked to pick a source workspace and then choose all or as many collections and environments as needed and finally `Add to this workspace`.

Whichever collections/environments you selected will now be duplicated to the new workspace.

---

Currently, there's no option to delete a collection or environment from a source workspace *while* copying it over. You will have to manually navigate inside a workspace to delete duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the collection, then Click `Move`

[image]

[image]